# Not able to install node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I have been trying to install node-sass using npm but it shows a postinstall error. I have already got the latest version of node and npm.
[image]

Comment: did you try to install it globally? `npm install -g node-sass`

Comment: @marcel same error on global too.

Comment: Works for me on Linux Mint with Node v5.3.0 and npm v3.5.1. Maybe try upgrading Node (4.2.4 is not the latest) — https://nodejs.org/en/download/stable/ Or follow this https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md

Comment: I am facing this issue - https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1283

Comment: I too am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue exactly, here is how i solve it:

1. Install node-gyp globally:

   **npm install node-gyp -g**
2. check if you are behind a proxy, if yes, then you need to create .npmrc file in windows user profile folder and add there your proxy details:

```
proxy=null
http-proxy=http://<proxy host>:<port>
https-proxy=http://<proxy host>:<port>
```

in Unix/OSX the .npmrc file should be in $HOME/.npmrc

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine had *exactly* the same problem this morning, after upgrading from an old Node.js version (with npm 3.x) to Node.js 8 with npm 5.

What helped here was quite simple:

- Delete the `node_modules` directory
- Run `npm install` to re-install *everything* again

Maybe it works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

use this flag `--unsafe-perm=true` Hope it will help.

```
sudo npm i gulp-sass -ES --unsafe-perm=true
```